# JavaScript. Сетка изображений

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Нужно создать сетку с изображениями (изображения выбираются рандомно), которая будет выводиться в div "pictures" после нажатия на кнопку. В JS я совсем не разбираюсь.

```
<script>
    var imgArr = new Array();

    imgArr[0] = new Image();
    imgArr[0].src = 'images/1.png';

    imgArr[1] = new Image();
    imgArr[1].src = 'images/2.png';

    imgArr[2] = new Image();
    imgArr[2].src = 'images/3.png';

    imgArr[3] = new Image();
    imgArr[3].src = 'images/4.png';

    imgArr[4] = new Image();
    imgArr[4].src = 'images/5.png';

    function myFunc() {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

            }
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    Rows: <input type="text" id="rows" />
    Columns: <input type="text" id="columns" /><br><br>
    <button onclick="myFunc();">Click</button>
</div>

<div id="pictures">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var imageBaseURL = 'http://scarlet.stanford.edu/scien/images/labsite/k0{INDEX}.bmp'
  , imageCount = 9;

(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var $rows = $('#rows')
      , $cols = $('#columns')
      , $container = $('#pictures');
    $('button').click(function() {
      var rows = $rows.val()
        , cols = $cols.val();
      if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
        $container.empty();
        for (var row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
          for (var col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageCount) + 1
              , image = $('<img/>').attr('src', imageBaseURL.replace('{INDEX}', index));
            col || image.addClass('clear');
            image.appendTo($container);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#pictures img {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#pictures img.clear {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Rows: <input type="number" min="1" step="1" id="rows" />
  Columns: <input type="number" min="1" step="1" id="columns" /><br><br>
  <button>Click</button><br><br>
</div>
<div id="pictures"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое